# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{s_t}{t}$, when $\sum_{i=1}^T s_i = A$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-analysis, time-series

consider the harmonic series: 
$$
h_T = \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{t}
$$
We know that $h_T \in O(\log T)$. Now consider a modified version of the harmonic series: 
$$
g_T = \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{s_t}{t}
$$
where $\sum_{i=1}^T s_i = A$. Is there an easy way to bound upper bound $g_T$ as a function of $A$ and $T$?

Comment: What's $t$?  Your index of summation doesn't appear in the summand :).  Why do you call $\log 1/t$ the harmonic series?

Comment: woops. corrected it.

Comment: $g_T = \sum_1^T \log s_t + h_T = log\left(∏_1^Ts_t\right) + h_T$, but I don't know an easy way to relate this product to the sum.

Comment: Actually, $h_T = \log(1/T!) \approx -T \log T + T + O(\log T)$.

Comment: The series you are calling $h_T$ is not the harmonic series, nor is it $O(\log T)$. The harmonic series is $\sum \frac 1 t$, not $\sum \log \frac 1 t$

Comment: Ah @PaulSinclair corrected.

Comment: Sorry for the whole mess I created. I had a redundant `log` in the definition, which correctly pointed our by @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 2):

What might be useful is
Chebychev's sum inequality:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality

If the $s_i$ are decreasing,
since $\frac1{t}$ is decreasing,
this says that
$\frac1{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{s_t}{t}
\ge \left(\frac1{T}\sum_{t=1}^T s_t\right)\left( \frac1{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \frac1{t}\right)
= \frac{A}{T}\frac{h_T}{T}
$
or
$g_T
\ge \frac{A h_T}{T}
$.

If the $s_i$ are increasing,
this says that
$\frac1{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{s_t}{t}
\le \frac1{T}\sum_{t=1}^T s_t \frac1{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \frac1{t}
= \frac{A}{T}\frac{h_T}{T}
$
or
$g_T
\le \frac{A h_T}{T}
$.

Comment: Thanks marty, I had an extra \log in the problem definition, which I corrected. Sorry for my mistake. I apologize that my mistake wasted your time.

Comment: I have another idea. I will replace my answer.